# ViewStack Vs State

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Can anyone explain difference between the ViewStack and States?

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ViewStack and States actually aren't really related.  Can you rephrase to make your question more specific?

The ViewStack is a component that is used to display different views (normally of different data, but not necessarily), one at a time.

States are related views of a single set of data.  For example, you may want to have a 'normal' view and an 'advanced' view of, say, a user's profile - where the advanced view displays more options, or a larger picture, etc.

States work with Transitions, which are coordinated animations that elegantly switch between states.

That's a real brief explanation.  Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Although, you can use both for the same purpose, but the way I see it, I think `ViewStack` is more of a container, think of it as like a book that you can flip to the different pages of.

In a `State`, you can apply a set changes to various different components, and when you change to that state, those changes will be applied.  When you go back to original state, the changes are removed.  That way you wouldn't have to recode all the components if you want to show them again, but only slightly differently.  You'd have to do that if you use a `ViewStack`.

There are a lot of changes between Flex 3 and Flex 4 State changes.

http://blog.everythingflex.com/2009/05/12/flex-3-vs-flex-4-state-management/